# Bloat a javascript file to make it bigger

Tags: javascript, performance

this is a rather odd question but I need to increase the filesize of javascript files as you normally want to reduce the size :)

So I was wondering on what would be the best way to bloat a javascript file with useless code yet make the browser parse the javascript file as fast as possible and hopefully use as little memory as possible.

The way I thought of was to maybe just put a lot of these until desired filesize has been reached.
    function(){ return undefined; };

Comment: Whats wrong with whitespace?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? And still getting a good performance and little memory?

Comment: im curious! Tell us why!

Comment: `/* junk here */`

Comment: I'm with Paul - just append spaces to the end of the file.

Comment: Go to a *lorem ipsum* generator, generate a million paragraphs of text and paste it in a comment.

Comment: I think you should make some kick ass ASCII-art! You could gzip the response to minimize the bandwidth usage.

Comment: cool ascii-art collection: http://welcomemat.co/

Comment: Click the "javascript" button on SO and you have direct access to *tons* of "useless code" :-)

Comment: Whitespace or comment will fit this bill, filling the code with function declarations is probably the worst you could do with regards to your goal.

Comment: `var youCouldAlsoUseExcessivelyLongVariableNamesToBloatYourJavascriptFile = true;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How large is the desired filesize? I doubt you'll have a noticeable problem with performance or memory unless it's a ridiculous size.

I would just add lots of comments and lots of whitespace.

As the others mentioned, please tell us why. ***We are engineers, we must know.***

Answer (score 0):

You could add the source of any major or minor Javascript library and remove the line where the object is added to the window scope. jQuery, D3.js, Backbone, Underscore, ... 
jQuery 1.10 unminified is about 90kb, Backbone would be 58kb unminified.